# Comma separated list to Columns / Mac Numbers

Tags: numbers, csv

I have a very huge list of Data (.txt file) .e.g.

```
945874,stu2,3826,120558,74,15
1836682,CHAOSTAURUS,90,978,3853,0
1411981,KasiaLover,101,28285,684,5
8270041,Daniel33de,3883,2389,2397,1
..... etc
```

where the variables are (in order):

```
$id, $name, $all_id, $points, $rank, $t
```

how can I convert every comma separated variable to it's own Column?

Can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the file extension to .csv then open the file with Numbers.

[image]